# DocuSignAPI -- createClient intermittently throws an error

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to integrate with DocuSign via DocuSignAPI. I call createClient with email and password, and sometimes it works as expected, but more often than not it prints out the following exception:

```
Unhandled rejection DocuSignError: Error getting API token: {
  "code": "ENOTFOUND",
  "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
  "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
  "hostname": "demo.docusign.net",
  "host": "demo.docusign.net",
  "port": 443
}
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your request going through any proxy layer first? Historically when I heard of intermittent API connectivity issues it was related to a bum proxy that would get used occasionally.  Also I take it you are using the docusign-node-client as well.

Comment: What language, environment, etc?  Please show the code in question too, not just the error you're getting...

Comment: That's a good point this is Node with docusign-node-client. The line that seems to be causing this is: 

    docusign.createClient(process.env.DOCUSIGN_EMAIL,        process.env.DOCUSIGN_PASSWORD, function (err, response) {
            if(err){
                return next(err);
            }
            docusign.client = response;
            next(null, docusign.client);

        });

Comment: Update: I tried using the example code from DocuSign documentation/github at https://github.com/docusign/devcenter-quickstarts/blob/master/2-EmbeddedSigning/embeddedSigning.js and I get the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

I get those intermittently from our Node.js app. Not just from the createClient endpoint, but all Docusign endpoints. About one fails in 20 tries. I'm going to wrap our handler with a 3x retry mechanism.

Comment: Consider using comments if you with to make remarks with information that may be helpful. Avoid posting your comments as an answer unless you are actually answering the question with something definitive.